# Variable "theme" is used before being assigned

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

I have a variable `theme` that is bound to get assigned itself a value from the `for` loop:

```js
let theme: Theme

for (const themeObj of themeList) {
  const [muiThemeName, muiTheme] = Object.entries(themeObj)[0]!;
  if (muiThemeName === themeName) {
    theme = muiTheme;
    break;
  } else theme = defaultTheme;
}
```

But still the TS Compiler complains that 'theme' is unassigned.

I know that I can do `theme!` to get away with it. But, it doesnt make sense, `theme` is going to always get assigned with something because `if...else` is used to assign it.

Thanks.

Comment: Assign the default when declaring the variable? `let theme: Theme = defaultTheme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is correct here.

If `themeList` is an empty array (a perfectly valid value for an array type), then your loop never runs once. In that case no value would ever be assigned.

Instead you should set the default first, then let your loop override it if necessary.

```
let theme: Theme = defaultTheme;

for (const themeObj of themeList) {
  const [muiThemeName, muiTheme] = Object.entries(themeObj)[0]!;
  if (muiThemeName === themeName) {
    theme = muiTheme;
    break;
  }
}
```